# Binding IEnumerable in ViewModel not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ViewModel - Customer. Within this there is an IEnumerable collection:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagNo{ get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I output a list of tags to the page - along with the scalar customer information - using a foreach:

```
...output customer info....
<div class="col-md-9">
    @{
        foreach (var Tag in Model.Tags)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => Tag.TagNo);
            <br />
        }
    }
</div>
```

I am attempting to hide the tag list in the page for the model binder so on errors I don't need to hit the database again:

```
@{
    int[] tagArray = Model.Tags.Select(x => x.TagNo).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Tags[" + i + "]", tagArray[i])
    }
}
```

This outputs this:

```
<input id="Tags_0_" name="Tags[0]" type="hidden" value="21111111" />
etc
```

I have seen various questions on SO saying you can use an array (as above) in a certain format that the model binder will understand for binding lists - eg:

[Creating HiddenFor IEnumerable<String> in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981979/creating-hiddenfor-ienumerablestring-in-view)

However, when the page has an error and I use the debugger to see what has been bound on the post, Although model.tags appears to have 3 elements - they are all empty.

I have also tried this:

```
@Html.Hidden("Tags[" + i + "].TagNo", tagArray[i])
```

But the Customer.Tags collection is empty after posting.

What am I doing wrong? How can I hide this list of tags in the page so that the model binder will see it?

Comment: Use the strongly typed helpers - `@Html.Hidden(m => m[i].Tags.TagNo)`(ditto for `CreatedDate`) so you generate the correct html. But why are you doing this - just get the collection again in the POST method if you need it. Generating all that extra html and sending it to the client and then sending it back again unchanged is just degrading performance. Note the `Tags` property needs to be `IList<Tag>`

Comment: Thx - I am doing this so I if there is a model error I don't have to hit the database to get the list again?! Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you have set up client side validation, then its rare that you would ever need to hit return the view. Just get it from the database again

Answer (score 1):

Your model property is `IEnumerable<Tag>` but following line(s) posting `int[]`.

you need change

```
@{
    int[] tagArray = Model.Tags.Select(x => x.TagNo).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Tags[" + i + "]", tagArray[i])
    }
}
```

to

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Tags.Count; i++)
{
   <input id="Tags_@(i)__TagNo" name="Tags[@i].TagNo" type="hidden" value="@Model.Tags[i].TagNo" />
}
```

I recommend that using editor templates for such situations

\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Tag.cshtml :

```
@model mvcTest.Models.Tag
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.TagNo)
```

parent view :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Tags.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Tags[i])
}
```

Comment: When you use an `EditorTemplate`, its just `@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Tags)` - no loops required - the method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and renders the correct html for each item in the collection.